# Is there any way to encrypt only data that are not encrypted yet?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there any way to encrypt only data that are not encrypted yet?(Is there any way you can tell encrypted and non-encrypted data apart?)

Please assume that I have a column that some data are already encrypted but some are not.

Code for encrypt

```
update usersExample3 set password=aes_encrypt(password,'1234');
```

I have a stored procedure that I have to fix it but not sure how:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE de ()
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'A procedure'
BEGIN
 while(there is any not encrypted data in the table)
  --if(usersExample3.password is not encrypted yet)
       update usersExample3 set password=aes_decrypt(password,'1234');
  --else (do nothing)
END//

;
```

Sample of my database:

```
select * from usersExample3 where userId<=5;


userId  username    password            salt
1       Tom         Password1234        NULL
4       bdfg        Î¸¨¾jj;öN/yë‘   bcv
5       test        test                test
```

So here I want to update all data that are not encrypted yet(in this sample are userId 1 and 5.
the problem is that everyone add data in database so when data saved in table, I have a trigger(after insert) that call this stored procedure to encrypt the new data automatically.
Thanks

Comment: The question that needs to be answered first is: "Is there any way you can tell encrypted and non-encrypted data apart?". Since we don't have your data we cannot answer this for you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sure, I added my table structure and some data samples

Comment: Don't encrypt like this if you want to know the difference. You need framing.

Comment: Am I then right in assuming you cannot tell encrypted and non-encrypted data apart? How did you end up in this situation?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware So the problem is that everyone add data in database so when data saved in table, I have a trigger(after insert) that call this stored procedure to encrypt the new data automatically.

Comment: @tadman So would you please help me to understand framing?

Comment: For password storage, you probably want to use *hashing*, not encryption. The difference is that you can't un-hash, so it's more secure. You want passwords to be verifiable without being decryptable. See this old blog from Stack Overflow founder Jeff Atwood: [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/)

Comment: @BillKarwin I have to make passwords and some high important data secured, I might use Hashing for passwords but I have to use the encryption decryption methods for other data. Thank you so much for the helpful link, And I will use 3 layers encryption method to gain more security.

Comment: @Christiano Framing is like putting a prefix on the data: `raw:....` or `aes:....` as a very basic example so you can quickly identify, by substring, which form the data is in.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case - no, you can't tell encrypted and non-encrypted data apart. Buuut, looking at your example, perhaps we can come close. The non-encrypted passwords will have "normal" characters that people can type on their keyboards. The encrypted ones will have all sorts of binary junk that doesn't make sense. So the first idea is to simply check if the password has characters with ASCII codes <32 or >127.

However this is not fool-proof yet. Sometimes people use more complicated characters too. If someone enters `Glāžšķūņu rūķīši` as their password, it's still legit words in some language (Latvian in this case) but you'll probably think it as encrypted.

Which brings us to the question - what is the character set of the column? And this is one place which looks suspicious to me from the start, because how are you storing *both* normal text and binary junk in there? Smells like someone doesn't understand characters sets, because doing this would under normal circumstances create a big mess.

Anyway, in case it's utf-8 text stored in a latin-1 column (a common situation), you can actually use it to your advantage for now - all the cells that are *not* a valid utf-8 string (plus those that have characters <32) will be encrypted.

(However if this really is the case, I strongly advise you to fix it soon and ensure that utf-8 is used EVERYWHERE from the beginning to the end. MUCH less headache that way. Here's [mandatory reading](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) about the whole character set thingy)

Comment: Thank you so much! Its a big help, so my clients can only have a-z, A-Z and special characters such as space,@#$%^&*()_+~ and I think these are all ASCII codes between 32 and 127.  May you please add an example to how check if the 'Password' contains ASCII codes more than 127 or less than 127?

Comment: @Christiano - Personally, I'd do it in some other programming language rather than SQL. You might be able to pull it off somehow with MySQL's regular expressions, or maybe a user function that checked all the characters and used the `ASCII()` function on each one of them... But it'd be a lot of hassle. Much more simple to use something else you're proficient with (PHP?). Then, encrypt everything, and forget that there ever were plain-text passwords there.

Comment: @Christiano - While on the subject of passwords, there are two additional pieces of wisdom - first, as Bill Karwin already said, don't use encryption, use hashing. PHP has a nice support for BCRYPT, use that. It's good. Made especially for passwords. Also, it produces nice ASCII output, no binary junk. Second - make another column that tells you how the password was encrypted. As time passes, cryptography methods tend to get outdated. Someday you'll need to change it again. It'll be good to know which password is encrypted in which way. Because, again, you can't tell just by looking at it.

Comment: yes you are right, I can check with sql command in where clause "password <> CONVERT(password USING ASCII)" so it shows only not ASCII ones, Problem solved mostly :)

Comment: You are completely right, I will use hashing for passwords but for critical data i have to use encryption methods since I might need them and hashing method are not un-hashable

Comment: @Christiano - Just be aware that this is really, really hacky and you should in no way make a habit of this! :D